# How can i see if a TypeDefinition is a Struct?

Tags: c#, .net-core, metadata, low-level, system.reflection.metadata

I want to know if a [TypeDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadata.typedefinition?view=netcore-3.0) is a Struct, there is no way I can see since the TypeAttributes will just give me an ambiguity between struct and class.

this is for a Scanning program that is going to try and recreate the assembly at a high-level manner that is easy to programmatically optimize, trim and merge without actually needing to load the assembly file.

I'm doing this in Dotnet Core targated for >=2.0 applications.

Comment: in what way are the type attributes ambiguous? what `TypeAttributes` are you seeing for a class/struct respectively? And would it not be possible to just use `Type` instead?

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't want to have to load in the Assembly as I will inevitably unload it directly after as I'm only using it for reflective purposes.
and TypeAttributes do not give a clear definition between struct and class as they are both marked as TypeAttributes.Class.

Comment: does checking the `BaseType` to see if you can resolve it as `System.ValueType` help?

Comment: You should rather use reflection only load, than. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context

Comment: Can you not just use `System.Type`? Are `typeof(MyType).IsClass` and `typeof(MyType).IsValueType` not good enough?  I've never used TypeDefinition.  It looks like it's the info you can pull from the assembly metadata (without digging any further).  I'm guessing that if that information isn't there, it probably isn't there

Comment: @Holger Reflection Only Load is not Supported without using the ReflectiveContext Load Method witch I would rather avoiding since I don't want to load an Assembly that I will inevitably unload for nothing more than reflective purposes.

Comment: @Flydog57 I would rather avoid having to load in the Assembly just to Reflect it.

Comment: ah sorry, you are in core. Than I go with Marc and you should inspect BaseType.

Comment: Can you get any useful information from the `BaseType` property?  There isn't much variation in the base types of Value Types: They are either System.ValueType or System.Enum (I think that's it).  Boy, this end of the world is poorly documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after Suggestions from @Flydog57 and @Marc Gravell i looked at the BaseType,

which came out as System.ValueType.
Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Don't forget enums (base type is System.Enum, which I believe inherits from System.ValueType)

Comment: @Flydog57 I will add that into my library as well, but for this question System.ValueType was what I was after.